# Edit movie clip definition as3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm a bit new to as3, so forgive me if these are dumb questions. Two questions...

Premise:
I'm loading a character from a swf file, and want to add avatar to it. I have him animated walking and also standing (stand_mc, walk_mc). I also have his body parts separated out, so inside each of the animations mc's is a head_mc, body_mc, etc etc.

First question, how can I access the body parts for any animation? here's my code so far:

```
    var WalkAnim:Class = SWFLoader.getClass('walk_mc'); //Using Greensock loader; but it's the same as using appDomain.getDefinition();
    var walkAnim:MovieClip = new WalkAnim();
    addChild(walkAnim);
```

Second question, adding walkAnim just creates an instance of the mc definition. How can I edit the definition in the library to do something like..

```
    var Hat:Class = SWFLoader.getClass('accessory_hat_mc');
    var hat = new Hat();
    WalkAnim:addChild(Hat)//???
```

So that if I have multiple instances on stage, they'll all be updated. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to access child elements, you use dot syntax. That would look something like this (last line):

```
var WalkAnim:Class = SWFLoader.getClass('walk_mc');
var walkAnim:WalkAnim = new WalkAnim(); // I have typed your var as WalkAnim, not MovieClip.
addChild(walkAnim);
walkAnim.head_mc.rotation += 5;
```

To answer your second question, you wont be able to edit the definition at runtime. You can add an item to each instance though:

```
var Hat:Class = SWFLoader.getClass('accessory_hat_mc');
var myHat:Hat = new Hat();
walkAnim.head_mc.addChild(myHat);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the dot notation but I can only see some of the parts for some reason. I see head and legs, but no body.. Everything looks the same in my flash library.

Comment: Have you made sure there are no spelling mistakes, missing linkages or some of them not being movieclips?

Comment: Figured out I had to assign each part an instance name... Not entirely clear on the differences between instance names, AS Linkage, and the mc name (all are assigned in Flash).